# Animation is Too Slow in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to display animations consisting of up to 127 png files in my Android app. However, I can't get them to play as fast as I would like. As you can see below I create an `AnimationDrawable` object and add png files as frames to it. I call `animation.addFrame(frame, 1)` so the total animation should play for 127 ms (127 frames x 1 ms), but on my phone it takes more than a second to play. From profiling my code, I see `byte[]` contributes to most memory usage, and I try to solve this by resizing the images further. However, the speed of the animation is still nowhere close to 127 ms. What is the best course of action?

```
void createAnimation(AnimationDrawable animation, int endFrameIdx){
    for (int i = 0; i < endFrameIdx; i++) {
        String name = idArray[i]; // idArray contains name of png files
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, id);
        Drawable compressD = resize(d);
        animation.addFrame(compressD, 1);} // 1 ms per frame
    }
}

private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 90, 161, true);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageanim = findViewById(R.id.imageanim);
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    int stopFrameIdx = 270; // maximum # of frames to add to animation
    createAnimation(animation, stopFrameIdx);
    imageanim.setImageDrawable(animation);
    animation.start();
```

Profiled Code. Resizing the png files reduces memory consumed by `byte[]`, but animation still plays slowly.

[image]

Comment: "Too Slow in Android Studio" you mean in the emulator?

Comment: No, I mean on a real phone, specifically Samsung galaxy grand prime

Comment: Bitmap images... Perhaps, caching your images beforehand can make it smoother. E.g. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: You are doing  some sort of resizing and I guess at main thread, you can try to put some of this calculations in background thread and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

After trying to optimize my code and failing to see major improvements, my best guess for now is that the animation is limited by the phone display refresh rate (60 hz). Though I'm confused why android supports methods that display frames at smaller time intervals.